# Setup for google sign in auth flutter aad oauth on app side

Tags: flutter, azure-active-directory, google-signin

What do I need to set up on the app side in order to setup for google login to work with azure aad auth.

https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth

Here is the package I am using. When signing in with google

`await oauth!.getIdToken();`

returns null. I believe I am missing some setup on the app end, azure google login is functional from the website.

Comment: Is your app already registered in Azure AD and have you provided the necessary scopes to get the ID token? To authorize and exchange tokens with your tenant, you need to provide the client id, a redirect URL, and discovery URL. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-azure-authentication-with-ad-b2c-8b76c81dd48e